# How does the new interface method Cassandra::get_paged_slice works and what is its purpose?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

In the updated Cassandra thrift interface I found new service method `get_paged_slice` but it still not described in wiki.

Who can explain me how does it works and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is intended to iterate over all columns of row range. It should be used when the rows are too long, and the method `get_range_slices` is inconvenient.

The method returns all columns of the row specified by `KeyRange`, starting from column specified by `start_column`. If the row ends before collecting enough results, the response is filled up with starting columns of the next row. Next time it should be called with last returned row id and last column name as params.

I suppose, it's not described on wiki, since it's somewhat experimental yet (as of version 1.1.6):

- I may only return the whole row, there's no way to specify SlicePredicate;
- KeyRange.count is intended to specify row count, and here it's used to specify column count;
- There are open bugs in cassandra jira that look severe, for example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4596